# DataGridView - how to set column width?

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview, controls

I have a WinForms application with `DataGridView` control. My control has five
columns (say "Name", "Address", "Phone" etc)

I am not happy with default column width. I want to have more control over column appearance. What I want
is to be able to do one of the following:

- Set width of each column in percent
- Set width of each column in pixels
- Use some other best-practive method (make width to fit text etc)

Please suggest - which property to use and how.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can use the `DataGridViewColumn.Width` property to do it:

```
DataGridViewColumn column = dataGridView.Columns[0];
column.Width = 60;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.width.aspx

Comment: Thanks! I just realized why it was not working for me. MSDN says

If the specified value when setting this property is less than the value of the MinimumWidth property, the MinimumWidth property value is used instead.

Comment: Yes, width is not available directly to the Grid control, so you use ItemStyle.With to set its property.

Comment: To add to this, if working in visual studio, right-click, click edit columns and then scroll down. This property (i.e. column.width) will be there.

Comment: How would you do this if you're using a datasource? I set `AutoSizeMode` to None and then changed the width but I get the error `Property not available for that object.`.

Answer (score 44):

The following also can be tried:

```
DataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells
```

or use the other setting options in the [DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewautosizecolumnsmode?view=netframework-4.8) Enum

Comment: When using the option "Fill" the columns are spread out to fill the full width of the grid.

Comment: For those wondering where it can be found on the designer's properties (GUI), it's under **Layout**, not **Appearance**.

Answer (score 28):

Most of the above solutions assume that the parent `DateGridView` has `.AutoSizeMode` not equal to `Fill`.  If you set the `.AutoSizeMode` for the grid to be `Fill`, you need to set the AutoSizeMode for each *column* to be `None` if you want to fix a particular column width (and let the other columns Fill).  I found a weird MS exception regarding a null object if you change a Column Width and the `.AutoSizeMode` is not `None` first.

This works

```
chart.AutoSizeMode  = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
... add some columns here
chart.Column[i].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
chart.Column[i].Width = 60;
```

This throws a null exception regarding some internal object regarding setting border thickness.

```
chart.AutoSizeMode  = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
... add some columns here
 // chart.Column[i].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
chart.Column[i].Width = 60;
```

Answer (score 22):

I know this is an old question but no one ever answered the first part, *to set width in percent.*  That can easily be done with [FillWeight](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.fillweight(v=vs.110).aspx) (MSDN).  In case anyone else searching comes across this answer.

You can set DataGridAutoSizeColumnMode to Fill in the designer.  By default that gives each column FillWeight of 100.  Then in code behind, on FormLoad event or after binding data to grid, you can simply:

```
gridName.Columns[0].FillWeight = 200;
gridName.Columns[1].FillWeight = 50;
```

And so on, for whatever proportional weight you want.  If you want to do every single column with numbers that add up to 100, for a literal percent width, you can do that too.

It gives a nice full DataGrid where the headers use the whole space, even if the user resizes the window.  Looks good on widescreen, 4:3, whatever.

Answer (score 10):

Regarding your final bullet

> make width fit the text

You can experiment with the .AutoSizeMode of your DataGridViewColumn, setting it to one of these values:

```
None
AllCells
AllCellsExceptHeader
DisplayedCells
DisplayedCellsExceptHeader
ColumnHeader
Fill
```

More info on the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewautosizecolumnmode.aspx) page

Answer (score 4):

i suggest to give a width to all the grid's columns like this :

```
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
col.HeaderText = "phone"            
col.Width = 120;
col.DataPropertyName = (if you use a datasource)
thegrid.Columns.Add(col);
```

and for the main(or the longest) column(let's say address) do this :

```
col = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
col.HeaderText = "address";
col.Width = 120;
```

tricky part

```
col.MinimumWidth = 120;
col.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
```

tricky part

```
col.DataPropertyName = (same as above)
thegrid.Columns.Add(col);
```

In this way, if you stretch the form (and the grid is "dock filled" in his container) the main column, in this case the address column, takes all the space available, but it never goes less than col.MinimumWidth, so it's the only one that is resized.

I use it, when i have a grid and its last column is used for display an image (like icon detail or icon delete..) and it doesn't have the header and it has to be always the smallest one.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void ArrangeGrid(DataGridView Grid)
{ 
    int twidth=0;
    if (Grid.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        twidth = (Grid.Width * Grid.Columns.Count) / 100;
        for (int i = 0; i < Grid.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
            Grid.Columns[i].Width = twidth;
            }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
yourdataView.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DataGridView1.Columns.Item("Adress").Width = 60
    DataGridView1.Columns.Item("Phone").Width = 30
    DataGridView1.Columns.Item("Name").Width = 40
    DataGridView1.Columns.Item("Etc.").Width = 30
```

Comment: This works just great in VB.net WinForms. It helped me after 5 years. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I you dont want to do it programmatically, you can manipulate to the Column width property, which is located inside the Columns property.Once you open the column edit property you can choose which column you want to edit, scroll down to layout section of the bound column properties and change the width.

Answer (score 1):

You can set default width and height for all Columns and Rows as below only with one loop.

```
    // DataGridView Name= dgvMachineStatus

   foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dgvMachineStatus.Columns)
        {
            column.Width = 155;
        }

   foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvMachineStatus.Rows)
        {
            row.Height = 45;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Columns Property and set the Auto Size Mode to All Cells, Resizable to True, Frozen to False and visible to True.

The column will automatically resize based on the data inserted.

Answer (score 0):

simply

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].FillWeight = 20;
```

Answer (score -3):

or Simply you can go to the form and when you call the data to be displayed you set the property 
like 
 datagridview1.columns(0).width = 150
 datagridview1.columns(1).width = 150
 datagridview1.columns(2).width = 150`enter code here`

So simple worked so fine with me Bro