# Programatically set column width in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DGV I am binding to a list of objects. I set AutoSizeColumnsMode to Fill, so that the columns stretch to fill the entire DGV, however, currently they stretch in a way so all columns are equal width. How can i specify a weightage so that the first column be 30% of the width and the other be 70%?

Comment: Apologies. Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154154/datagridview-how-to-set-column-width

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most specifically it appears to me you could use "AutoSizeColumsMode" = "Fill" and then set "FillWeight" on each Column to the % you were looking for.